# WHERE LIKE with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fairly complicated query which searches across 4 tables for one or more keywords:

```
select distinct textures.id from textures
left join `category_texture` on `category_texture`.`texture_id` = `textures`.`id`
left join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `category_texture`.`category_id`
left join `tag_texture` on `tag_texture`.`texture_id` = `textures`.`id`
left join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `tag_texture`.`tag_id`
left join `size_texture` on `size_texture`.`texture_id` = `textures`.`id`
left join `sizes` on `sizes`.`id` = `size_texture`.`size_id` 
WHERE ( (textures.name LIKE '%artwork%' 
OR categories.name LIKE '%artwork%' 
OR tags.name LIKE '%artwork%'   
OR sizes.name LIKE '%artwork%')  AND  (textures.name LIKE '%super%' 
OR categories.name LIKE '%super%'   
OR tags.name LIKE '%super%' 
OR sizes.name LIKE '%super%')  AND  (textures.name LIKE '%master%' 
OR categories.name LIKE '%master%'  
OR tags.name LIKE '%master%'    
OR sizes.name LIKE '%master%') ) AND `textures`.`is_published` = 1  group by `tags`.`name`, `categories`.`name`, `sizes`.`name`, `textures`.`id`
```

In this example, artwork is a category, master and super are tags. The problem is that if I repeat any of the tables, no results are found:

1. artwork (category) + master (tag) works
2. artwork works
3. artwork + master + super does NOT work - it should print all the textures which have artwork as category and 2 tags (master AND super), but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Editing for clarity:

My goal is to be able to search for data within those tables, in a way that I can combine multiple instances of the same table. For instance, if I search for "artwork super master", it should return all my textures with category "artwork" (because it's the only place where the word is found) and the tags "super" and "master" (both of them).

Currently with this query I'm able to search from within any of those tables, but only if my search doesn't find 2+ things in the same table. So, searching for a category + a texture name + a tag + a size works, but searching for something which is found as 2 tags fails.

Comment: Seeing an example of the data being queried would _really_ help people here. I assume this is the most strict query 3, as it is filtering for artwork, super, and master. (Meaning 1 and 2 are not shown.) Also, what do you mean by "if I repeat any of the tables"?

Comment: Edited my post with a better explanation.

Comment: this seems like the kind of thing `full text search` was created for. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm being asked to solve this "as is", without going for full text search :(

Comment: The query shown will only return you rows for which each of the 3 tags exists in at least 1 of the 4 tables. It is doing precisely what you have told it to. You seem to need to search for _single_ instances of each table (query) using pattern-matching, not the "multiple tables" you keep mentioning. How are you going to be searching? How is the search pattern going to be input into your database?

Comment: Uh, more to the point, can't you just change those `) AND (` separators between each tag clause, to `) OR (`? That would change the behaviour from 'require all 3 tags in at least 1 table each' to 'require at least 1 tag in at least 1 table'.

Comment: Through a PHP framework. The code I added is just for debugging purposes, I'm escaping the parameters in the real code. If I search for _single_ instances of each table, I wouldn't be able to get results for something which had two tags, or am I thinking wrong? E.g. if I searched for "tag1 tag2", it would only retrieve the results for tag1.

Comment: I think this "instances of each table" thing is a wrong term. You are querying a bunch of tables, each included once in a `JOIN`, then checking them for 3 tags.. Each of your `) AND (` separated conditions is saying 'Require this tag in at least 1 of these `JOIN`ed tables'. You have 3 such conditions, so you will require all 3 tags. If you want to search for _1 or more_ tags, use `) OR (`. Please try this out with your dataset.

Comment: I changed it to this - http://pastebin.com/nF0WWsxq - now it always gives me the full list of results no matter what I search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a rethink and perhaps this approach is better:

```
SELECT T1.id
FROM 
(  
select textures.id 
from textures
WHERE textures.name LIKE '%texture1%' 
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join category_texture on category_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join categories on categories.id = category_texture.category_id
WHERE categories.name LIKE '%texture1%'
UNION
select textures.id 
from textures
join tag_texture on tag_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join tags on tags.id = tag_texture.tag_id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%texture1%'
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join size_texture on size_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join sizes on sizes.id = size_texture.size_id 
WHERE sizes.name LIKE '%texture1%'
) AS T1
JOIN 
(  
select textures.id 
from textures
WHERE textures.name LIKE '%category2%' 
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join category_texture on category_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join categories on categories.id = category_texture.category_id
WHERE categories.name LIKE '%category2%'
UNION
select textures.id 
from textures
join tag_texture on tag_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join tags on tags.id = tag_texture.tag_id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%category2%'
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join size_texture on size_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join sizes on sizes.id = size_texture.size_id 
WHERE sizes.name LIKE '%category2%'
) AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
JOIN
(  
select textures.id 
from textures
WHERE textures.name LIKE '%tag3%' 
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join category_texture on category_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join categories on categories.id = category_texture.category_id
WHERE categories.name LIKE '%tag3%'
UNION
select textures.id 
from textures
join tag_texture on tag_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join tags on tags.id = tag_texture.tag_id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%tag3%'
UNION 
select textures.id 
from textures
join size_texture on size_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join sizes on sizes.id = size_texture.size_id 
WHERE sizes.name LIKE '%tag3%'
) AS T3
ON T1.id = T3.id
```

Just add more/less `JOIN...ON T1.id = Tn.id` sections to match your parameters.

Here is a fiddle to show it executing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9abe6/1

Comment: Note: I left out the `AND textures.is_published = 1` and `group by whatever` clauses to keep it simple. I think it will need `AND textures.is_published = 1` in every select. Add the `group` yourself if needed.

Comment: I'm going to run some tests with this and let you know. Basically I need these tests to pass: 1) searching for "category2" will retrieve all textures with that category; 2) searching for "category2 tag3" will retrieve textures which match these specific informations (in this case, only textures with category2 as category and tag3 as tag should show); 3) searching for "tag1 tag2 tag3" should retrieve only the textures which in this case have those 3 categores or more.

Comment: I've made a few adaptations but your edited answer worked exactly like I had in mind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with what your query is trying to do. First, the number of parameters can vary which requires a different query syntax for each variation (or some ugly hack to work around it). Secondly, for each table you want to return only rows which match one of the parameters *unless there are no matches* when you want to return all rows.

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
select distinct textures.id 
from textures
join category_texture on category_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join categories on categories.id = category_texture.category_id
join tag_texture on tag_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join tags on tags.id = tag_texture.tag_id
left join size_texture on size_texture.texture_id = textures.id
join sizes on sizes.id = size_texture.size_id 
WHERE ((textures.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR textures.name LIKE '%super%' OR textures.name LIKE '%master%')  
  OR   (0 = select count(*) from textures where (textures.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR textures.name LIKE '%super%' OR textures.name LIKE '%master%') ) )
AND   ((categories.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR categories.name LIKE '%super%' OR categories.name LIKE '%master%') 
  OR   (0 = select count(*) from categories where (categories.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR categories.name LIKE '%super%' OR categories.name LIKE '%master%') ) )
AND   ((tags.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR tags.name LIKE '%super%' OR tags.name LIKE '%master%') 
  OR   (0 = select count(*) from tags where (tags.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR tags.name LIKE '%super%' OR tags.name LIKE '%master%') ) )
AND   ((sizes.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR sizes.name LIKE '%super%' OR sizes.name LIKE '%master%') 
  OR   (0 = select count(*) from name where (sizes.name LIKE '%artwork%' OR sizes.name LIKE '%super%' OR sizes.name LIKE '%master%') ) )
AND textures.is_published = 1   
group by textures.id, tags.name, categories.name, sizes.name, textures.name
```

**EDIT** Since your code dynamically generates the SQL, I have put in the values from the original example.

This whole query is incredibly ugly, but it should work.
If you need to do searches like this, you need to rethink your data structures.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem completely. This query is built dynamically through PHP, so the number of parameters doesn't really matter. Then, for each table I want to try and match any of the parameters _even if multiple parameters are match for the same table_. So, if in my 5 parameters there are two matches for category, 2 for tag and texture name, I want the results which have _exactly_ those 2 categories, 2 tags and texture name.

Comment: Thanks, I revised the answer to make it clearer what I was getting at. You can generate more/less code per the number of parameters as required. The only known issue with my (untested) code is that if there are no matches, it will return everything.