# How should I merge these selects and narrow the result set?

Tags: mysql, search

I have this huge query that filters results out of a series of keywords.

```
select distinct textures.id from textures
WHERE ((textures.id in (
        select tt.texture_id
        from tag_texture tt join tags t
        on t.id = tt.tag_id
        where t.name in ('tag1', 'tag2')
        group by tt.texture_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 2
        )
)  OR (textures.id in (
        select ct.texture_id
        from category_texture ct join categories c
        on c.id = ct.category_id
        where c.name in ('category1', 'category2')
        group by ct.texture_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 2
        )
)  OR (textures.id in (
        select tex.id
        from textures tex
        where tex.name LIKE 'texturename'
        group by tex.id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tex.id) = 1
        )
) ) AND textures.is_published = 1
```

The problem is that if I search for *texturename tag1*, all texturename results will be found, even if they have nothing to do with tags. However, if I search for "tag1 tag2", the resulting list is filtered out (less results than just searching tag1). Changing those ORs to AND widens the results even more, obviously.

What's the best way to merge these results so that each time a word is filtered the result set is narrowed down?

Comment: Do you want "tag1 tag2" to mean either of the words, or both of them?

Comment: Changing `OR` to `AND` should narrow it down, not widen it. I think it should do what you want.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 1` means you'll only select items that have exactly one of the tags, not both.

Comment: @Barmar you are right - I was copying/pasting a manually edited example and forgot to add = 2 (in this case). This query is being generated through PHP, but you are correct. Also, if I add AND instead of those two OR and search for "tag1 texturename" I get all "texturename" results, and not a narrowed list that should have texturename+tag1. That's my biggest problem as of now. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I still think that changing `OR` to `AND` should solve the problem, and I don't understand why it fails.

Comment: It sounds to me like you changed the first `OR`, but forgot to change the second `OR`.

Comment: @Barmar Here it is, sorry it took a while to create it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/1 - as you see, all three "apple" textures are being shown, even though only "Apple Two" has the needed tags and categories.

Comment: I changed `OR` to `AND` and it's just returning Apple Two: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/3

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that, the example was not the best. The problem is that I receive all the keywords from a form, so I match all of them against these cases - hence the OR not the AND. This is a better example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/7 (thanks a lot for your patience)

Comment: Your `COUNT` clauses are wrong again in that fiddle.

Comment: That fiddle seems to be completely different, because you're matching the same keywords against all the different fields. In that case it should return a texture that matches in just one of the fields, because you don't know which keywords should match each field.

Comment: Your form needs to have separate input fields for each field to search.

Comment: If you want to require that there be a match in each field, but you don't care which keyword matches where, get rid of the `HAVING COUNT` clauses.

Comment: I understand your point, but that's what I was trying to do: "merge these selects and narrow the result set". What I had in mind was something like "get the results for tags, subtract the match from categories, and then subtract the match for texture name". I'm sorry if I didn't explain it correctly (English is not my native tongue)

Comment: Why are you subtracting? Usually a search form specifies the keywords you want to view, not the ones you want to omit. You want to intersect them, and that's what AND does.

Comment: I want to search for "apple test 1k" and have the "Apple two" result - the only possible match for those 3 keywords, out of any possibility. I removed the HAVING COUNT clauses here, is there something missing? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/20

Comment: None of those match the categories. The only categories are `Artwork` and `Mine`.

Comment: I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: Indeed, but the idea is that any of these keywords may or may not be present in those subqueries. E.g. I can just search for "1k" and it should retrieve all the possibilities for 1k, you see? It's a tag-based search, more or less like SO does when we tag new posts, in a sense that you write things and separate them with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Changing all the `OR` to `AND` should solve the problem:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM textures
WHERE ((textures.id in (
        select tt.texture_id
        from tag_texture tt join tags t
        on t.id = tt.tag_id
        where t.name in ('1k', 'test')
        group by tt.texture_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 2
        )
)  AND (textures.id in (
        select ct.texture_id
        from category_texture ct join categories c
        on c.id = ct.category_id
        where c.name in ('mine')
        group by ct.texture_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 1
        )
)  AND (textures.id in (
        select tex.id
        from textures tex
        where tex.name LIKE '%apple%'
        group by tex.id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tex.id) = 1
        )
) ) AND textures.is_published = 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/6)

There's no need to use `DISTINCT` in this query. You're not joining with any other tables, so nothing is going to cause the results to multiply.

If you want to search for the same keywords in all the fields, and require that at least one of them match each field, get rid of the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

```
select textures.id, textures.name from textures
WHERE ((textures.id in (
        select tt.texture_id
        from tag_texture tt join tags t
        on t.id = tt.tag_id
        where t.name in ('1k', 'test', 'apple', 'mine')
        )
)  AND (textures.id in (
        select ct.texture_id
        from category_texture ct join categories c
        on c.id = ct.category_id
        where c.name in ('1k' 'test', 'apple', 'mine')
        )
)  AND (textures.id in (
        select tex.id
        from textures tex
        where tex.name LIKE '%1k%' OR tex.name LIKE '%test%' OR tex.name LIKE '%apple%'
          OR tex.name LIKE '%mine%'
        )
) ) AND textures.is_published = 1
```

I added `mine` to the list of keywords, because otherwise there was no match in the `categories` table.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/23)

Comment: This is almost good, however if I perform a simple search for "artwork" (category), no results are found. This current query only works if at least one keyword matches a tag, and another matches a category, and another matches a texture name. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4d5b/26

Comment: Ah, you don't want to match all the fields, you want to match every keyword, but they can be in any field. That's more complicated. You need a separate subquery for each keyword, and that will contain further subqueries that test each field.

Comment: Exactly. I ended up adapting this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418443/where-like-with-multiple-keywords - thanks a lot for your effort!